# GPU Allocation Issue -

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, word-embedding, knowledge-graph

I am training a knowledge graph model using pyKEEN library and the ComplExLiteral model. The problem is with a file which is 1.3 GB creating an allocation issue since the graphic card I am using is 24GB big.  now I am using 10% of the whole data instead of the complete 1.3 GB. Here is an idea regarding the training parameters and the error:

```
    def create_embedding_model(
    self,
    kg_training_loop="slcwa",
    kg_neg_sampler="bernoulli",
    kg_batch_size=128,
    kg_number_epochs=1,
):
    self.kg_logger.info("Starting to train the knowledge graph embedding model...")

    self.kg_embedding_model_pipeline = pipeline(
        training=self.triples_literals_factory,
        testing=self.triples_literals_factory,
        model=self.kg_embedding_model,
        training_kwargs=dict(
            num_epochs=kg_number_epochs,
            use_tqdm=True,
            batch_size=kg_batch_size,
        ),
        evaluation_kwargs=dict(
            use_tqdm=True,
            batch_size=kg_batch_size // 4
            if torch.cuda.is_available()
            else kg_batch_size,
        ),
        negative_sampler=kg_neg_sampler,
        training_loop=kg_training_loop,
        random_seed=self.kg_random_seed,
    )

    self.kg_embedding_initialized_model = self.kg_embedding_model_pipeline.model

    return self.kg_embedding_initialized_model
```

Error:

CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.09 GiB (GPU 0; 22.38 GiB total capacity; 2.00 GiB already allocated; 19.22 GiB free; 2.55 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation. See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF